# Cartthrob, Play Audio File, Content Disposition Issue

Tags: cartthrob

With my site I am are offering a file to be downloaded or to be played. Via mobile(iPhone) I am unable to play the audio file, I get the white play button with the slash through it. Android attempts to download the file, but it fails. I have set Content-Disposition to inline within the Cartthrob_file.php file, this gave me the ability to now play the file not download it via the browser. I have also changed the settings within that file to completely disable Content-Disposition so it would naturally default to inline, but no progress. I have looked around Cartthrobs docs and forums to get around the issue, but nothing.

My main focus(question) I am trying to give the user(purchaser) the ability to play the audio file via their phone while they are view the site. And do the whole right click to save file.

Comment: What kind of audio file? Does it download properly on a desktop browser? Start there before messing with changing the Content-Disposition. When it comes to audio, most browsers (mobile and not) are smart about how to behave these days.

Comment: Its a MP3, and it works perfectly in the browser. It just will not download on the phone.